# Variable global en Angular7

Tags: angular7

Necesito tener una variable en Angular7 que esté disponible en cualquier ámbito cuando le de a F12 -> console(pregunto por esa variable).

Angular funciona a base de componentes, por lo que crearlo en cualquier ámbito de un componente ya he visto que no funciona.

También he creado un `servicio.ts` para poner la variable pero como no estoy en "ninguna función" o modo depuración no puedo preguntar por ella.

Si intento poner el nombre de una variable del component.ts en el F12-> console, me dice que
`numeroCuentas is not defined`

No quiero suscribirme a ningún cambio de la variable, es cierto que dependiendo del componente que se ejecute la variable va a cambiar aunque sus valores puedo cambiarlos en el `ngOnInit` traiéndola del `servicio.ts` para que todos los componentes tiren de la misma variable, el problema es que no puedo imprimirla en el F12 -> console esté donde esté en la aplicación y necesito que se pueda imprimir en cualquier ámbito.

Siento no poder poner un código, pero no sé ni como se hace y sólo veo páginas preguntando por subscribirse a los cambios de las variables.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución, escribir en el index.html una variable ->

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var hola = 'algo';
  </script>
```

Luego acceder desde cualquier componente.ts -> Para mi caso lo usé al iniciar el componente y cambiar el valor:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let rootVar = window['hola'];
    rootVar += ' adios';
    window['hola'] = rootVar;
}
```

Recoges la variable, se le añade un nuevo valor y ya está disponible con F12 -> console -> nombre de la variable.

Comment: Realmente no necesitas crearla previamente, `window['cualquiercosa']` valdrá `undefined` si no está creada.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso yo prefiero utilizar un localstorage o sessionstorage, me parece es una solución más limpia y más sencilla. Aquí te dejo un link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage .

Puedes adicionar en el AppComponent.ts algo como esto:

```
  constructor() {
    localStorage.setItem('numeroCuentas', '0');
  }
```

Y luego al inspeccionar con el:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('numeroCuentas'))
```

obtendrás el valor. También desde cualquier componente podrás acceder a esa variable.

Comment: Por favor edita y amplia tu aporte, pues responder com solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Quizás esto es mejor ponerlo como un comentario. Pero no tengo los puntos suficientes para hacerlo y quería brindarle una posible solución.